# Wordpress getting comments issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress `get_comments()`, but it malfunctions. At the bottom of each post I see the same comments. I know get_comments has an ID attr, but How should I assign it dynamically? I'm using comments in single.php and getting them with `comment_template()`;

thanks in advance

EDIT

```
comment_form($comments_args);

$post_comments = get_comments();
?>

<?php
    if ( $post_comments )
    {       
?>
<section class='post-comments'>

<?php 


   foreach($post_comments as $comment_each)
{
     $comment_each->comment_content;
    } 

 ?>

</section>  
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <div class='no-comment'>
        <?php
        _e('No comments to show.'); 
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

While be

Comment: Get_comments does not malfunction, it just needs to be called correctly. Show us your code and we can help

Comment: Somebody please helps me

Comment: try get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $post->ID))

Comment: Hey body excellent solution! it all works. thanks so much.

Comment: you could reply to the post as a whole to make your reply a solution to raise your reputation

Comment: I have now, I didn't originally as I was not sure where this code was so $post may not have been set or may not have referenced the expected post if it was outside of a loop on a page with multiple posts, so it may not have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
$post_comments = get_comments();
```

with

```
$post_comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $post->ID))
```